# PHP odbc_connect vs sqlsrv_connect

Tags: php, odbc

I would like to run the latest version of php 8.3.1 but I can't find sql server drivers for 8.3.1.  I did find sql server drivers for php 8.2 and can connect successfully.  I also can connect successfully using odbc_connect.  My question is if I use use odbc, is there any significant downside?  I would prefer to use the latest version of php because of security issues.

Comment: You probably just need to be a little bit patient. 8.3 was only just released, Microsoft will probably release drivers soon enough for it. https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1477#issuecomment-1866726170 . Maybe for now you can use PHP 8.2 while you are waiting, it ought to be easy enough to upgrade once the SQL Server driver is also available.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like the beta came out and is working fine